# PSQL Case insensitive search using Exposed

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

How can we do case insensitive search using Exposed(Kotlin) on a postgres sql database?

```
SELECT users.id, users.name, users.created_at, users.updated_at FROM users 
WHERE users.name iLIKE '%aaa%'
```

There is `like` operator. I don't see `ilike` operator. Should I be using lowercase on the query field?

Comment: [ILIKE is PSQL's case-insensitive LIKE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html). SQL is case-insensitive, so it doesn't matter if you write it like `ILIKE` or `ilike` or anything in between.

Comment: @m0skit0 Sorry if the question isn't clear. It's not about the case(lower/upper) in which ilike is used. It is about using iLike operator with exposed library. I don't find any method which provides the functionality of case insensitive search in the Library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ILIKE` is PostgreSQL specific function and doesn't support in Exposed at the moment, but you can define it by your own :

```
class ILikeOp(expr1: Expression<*>, expr2: Expression<*>) : ComparisonOp(expr1, expr2, "ILIKE")

infix fun<T:String?> ExpressionWithColumnType<T>.ilike(pattern: String): Op<Boolean> = ILikeOp(this, QueryParameter(pattern, columnType))
```